# Return ImageView instance when i click on the item GridView

Tags: c#, android, xamarin.android, mvvmcross

How to return ImageView instance when i click on the item GridView?

**I create custom bindings event for ItemClick:**

```
public class ItemClickSquareBinding
        : MvxBaseAndroidTargetBinding
    {
        private readonly GridView _gridView;
        private IMvxCommand _command;

        public ItemClickSquareBinding(GridView gridView)
        {
            _gridView = gridView;
            _gridView.ItemClick += GridView_ItemClick;
        }

        private void GridView_ItemClick(object sender, AdapterView.ItemClickEventArgs e)
        {
            //----->Get ImageView
        }

        public override void SetValue(object value)
        {
            _command = (IMvxCommand)value;
        }

        protected override void Dispose(bool isDisposing)
        {
            if (isDisposing)
            {
                _gridView.ItemClick -= GridView_ItemClick;
            }
            base.Dispose(isDisposing);
        }

        public override Type TargetType
        {
            get { return typeof(IMvxCommand); }
        }

        public override MvxBindingMode DefaultMode
        {
            get { return MvxBindingMode.OneWay; }
        }
    }
```

**My GridView:**

```
<cirrious.mvvmcross.binding.android.views.MvxBindableGridView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:numColumns="4"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:listSelector="#00000000"
        local:MvxItemTemplate="@layout/itemimage"
        local:MvxBind="{'ItemsSource':{'Path':'Squares'}, 'ClickItemSquare':{'Path':'ClickCommand'}}" />
```

**My ImageView:**

```
<ImageView
      xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      xmlns:local="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/LeSommet.ZooSnap.UI.Android"
      android:layout_width="80dp"
      android:layout_height="80dp"
      android:padding="5dp"
      android:layout_gravity="center"
      local:MvxBind="{'ResourcesImagePath':{'Path':'ImagePath'}}"
  />
```

**How to return ImageView instance when i click on the item GridView? (or how I may return instance of object which clicked me)**

Comment: you originally tagged this as 'C# android monocross' - none of which alerted me that this was a 'monodroid mvvmcross' question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Three answers below ... I prefer the one marked **3**

#### 1) A Simpler Approach

At a really basic level, I think you can just use the built-in binding for this.

Looking at `ItemClick` in https://github.com/slodge/MvvmCross/blob/vnext/Cirrious/Cirrious.MvvmCross.Binding.Droid/Views/MvxBindableGridView.cs you should be able to just do:

```
<cirrious.mvvmcross.binding.android.views.MvxBindableGridView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:numColumns="4"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:listSelector="#00000000"
    local:MvxItemTemplate="@layout/itemimage"
    local:MvxBind="{'ItemsSource':{'Path':'Squares'}, 'ItemClick':{'Path':'ClickCommand'}}" />
```

where `ClickCommand` is something like:

```
public ICommand ClickCommand { get { return new MvxRelayCommand<Square>(square => square.Foo()); } }
```

If this doesn't work, then please [raise a bug with test code](https://github.com/slodge/MvvmCross/issues/new) - the grid was community donated to MvvmCross so it's not something I've used yet.

---

#### 2) To make your custom binding work

If you do want to do the custom binding.

Using Intellisense, it looks like an `AdapterView.ItemClickEventArgs` has a couple of potentially useful properties:

```
        e.View;
        e.Position;
```

So you can access the `View` if you want to - and can then use things like `FindViewById<>` to find contained views.

Or you can access the `Position` and can then:
- use Adapter methods like `public override Object GetItem(int position)` to get a Java wrapped object from your original array
- or can use accessor method direct on your incoming array or enumerable.

---

#### 3) The way I normally work

I generally don't do this sort of custom binding when all I want to do is click on a list item or part of a list item.

Instead I write my ViewModels so that they expose behaviour-enabled collections - I try to present a behaviour-enabled wrapper of the Model object rather than the Model object itself.

In this approach the ViewModel exposes a `List<WrappedSquare>` instead of a `List<Square>`

```
public WrappedSquare
{
   Square _saure;
   SquareViewModel _square;

   public WrappedSquare(Square square, SquareViewModel parent)
   {
       /* assignment */
   }

   public ICommand TheCommand { get { return MvxRelayCommand(() -> _parent.DoStuff(_square)); } }

   public Square TheSquare { get { return _square; } } 
}
```

The axml within the list item then has bindings like:

```
<ImageView
      xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      xmlns:local="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/LeSommet.ZooSnap.UI.Android"
      android:layout_width="80dp"
      android:layout_height="80dp"
      android:padding="5dp"
      android:layout_gravity="center"
      local:MvxBind="{'ResourcesImagePath':{'Path':'TheSquare.ImagePath'},'Click':{'Path':'TheCommand'}}"
  />
```

and the axml for the grid is:

```
<cirrious.mvvmcross.binding.android.views.MvxBindableGridView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:numColumns="4"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:listSelector="#00000000"
    local:MvxItemTemplate="@layout/itemimage"
    local:MvxBind="{'ItemsSource':{'Path':'WrappedSquares'}}" />
```

This example code is adapted from [MVVMCross changing ViewModel within a MvxBindableListView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12682082/mvvmcross-changing-viewmodel-within-a-mvxbindablelistview) - the answer there is relevant to this question too.

---

One real example of this approach is the Conference sample which uses `WithCommand<T>` to enable navigation from lists to detail views.

However... there is one warning on this approach - please note that when using `WithCommand<T>` we discovered a memory leak in iOS/MonoTouch - basically the GarbageCollection refused to collect the embedded `MvxRelayCommand` - which is why `WithCommand<T>` is `IDisposable` and why `BaseSessionListViewMode` clears the list and disposes the `WithCommand` elements when views are detached.

Comment: I need it to run the animation and music when you click on Item GridView

Comment: Click is just a C# delegate - it can multicast to many event handlers

Answer (score 1):

A fourth answer (after comment on previous three...)

Bindings are about View-ViewModel communication.

Animation is not something the ViewModel or the Binding should really handle.

In my opinion, you would be better off using a custom control for your animation. For custom controls in MonoDroid, see [Xamarin Monodroid: WP7 => Android and Custom Control?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11091312/xamarin-monodroid-wp7-android-and-custom-control)