# MvxBindableGridView in a linearlayout doesnt bind to any items

Tags: xml, xamarin.android, mvvmcross

I was using a MvxBindableGridView in a relative layout and it was working perfectly. I then realized that I need to use LinearLayouts for my screens to scale properly across different devices. When I changed to a LinearLayout and run the app the GridView is empty and debug output shows some binding errors

```
12-03 16:55:38.363 I/MvxBind ( 2689):  14.25 Failed to create target binding for from ClickCommand to ClickItemSquare
MvxBind:Warning: 14.25 Failed to create target binding for from ClickCommand to ClickItemSquare
12-03 16:55:38.363 I/mono-stdout( 2689): MvxBind:Warning: 14.25 Failed to create target binding for from ClickCommand to ClickItemSquare
```

Does anyone know why this failed when it works perfectly in RelativeLayout?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:local="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/xxxxx"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent">
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/layoutresults"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textscore"
        local:MvxBind="{'Text':{'Path':'Score'}}"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="0000"
        android:textColor="#ff60350f"
        android:textSize="20dp"
        android:layout_x="25dp"
        android:layout_y="45dp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginTop="53dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="25dp" />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/layoutstartnewgame"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="65dp"
        android:layout_x="109dp"
        android:layout_y="23dp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        local:MvxBind="{'Click':{'Path':'StartNewGame'}}"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="27dp" />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/texttime"
        local:MvxBind="{'Text':{'Path':'Time'}}"
        android:text="00:00"
        android:textColor="#ff60350f"
        android:textSize="20dp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_x="245dp"
        android:layout_y="45dp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:layout_marginTop="53dp"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="23dp" />
</RelativeLayout>
<cirrious.mvvmcross.binding.android.views.MvxBindableGridView
    android:layout_below="@+id/layoutresults"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:numColumns="4"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:listSelector="#00000000"
    local:MvxItemTemplate="@layout/itemimage"
    local:MvxBind="{'ItemsSource':{'Path':'Squares'}, 'ClickItemSquare':{'Path':'ClickCommand'}}"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Changed to Linear

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:local="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/xxxxx"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:background="@drawable/TabletGameScreen">
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_weight=".1"
    android:gravity="center" />
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/layoutresults"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_weight=".1">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textscore"
        local:MvxBind="{&apos;Text&apos;:{&apos;Path&apos;:&apos;Score&apos;}}"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="0000"
        android:textColor="#ff60350f"
        android:textSize="20dp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical" />
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        local:MvxBind="{&apos;Click&apos;:{&apos;Path&apos;:&apos;StartNewGame&apos;}}"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical" />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/texttime"
        local:MvxBind="{&apos;Text&apos;:{&apos;Path&apos;:&apos;Time&apos;}}"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="00:00"
        android:textColor="#ff60350f"
        android:textSize="20dp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal" />
</LinearLayout>
<cirrious.mvvmcross.binding.android.views.MvxBindableGridView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_weight=".8"
    android:numColumns="4"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:listSelector="#00000000"
    local:MvxItemTemplate="@layout/itemimage"
    local:MvxBind="{&apos;ItemsSource&apos;:{&apos;Path&apos;:&apos;Squares&apos;}, &apos;ClickItemSquare&apos;:{&apos;Path&apos;:&apos;ClickCommand&apos;}}" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Can you provide more code than that? E.g. Exact before and after of what did and didn't work?

Answer (score 1):

The ClickItemSquare warnings are telling you that some binding is happening, but that the ClickCommand is not working.

Based on what little info there is in your question...

- Look at how ClickCommand is implemented - I'm guessing it's based on [Return ImageView instance when i click on the item GridView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13146942/return-imageview-instance-when-i-click-on-the-item-gridview) - but it's your code so no-one else can help you with it (unless you post it)
- Try setting the binding trace level to Verbose/Diagnostic to get more information out (look at MvxBindingTrace for how to do this - there's a static variable value to set)
- Check that you have android:orientation='vertical' to your LinearLayout
- Try stepping through the code - are property values on the ViewModel list items being called? If they are then you know binding is working
- Try reverting back to the Grid code - do you see the same ClickItemSquare warnings
- Try posting a question with more detail about the changes (e.g. some before and after code)

Comment: Ive added the code to original post for you to look at. Now whats interesting on the LinearLayout version if I change the top level LinearLayout to a RelativeLayout it will display and work again, but I can't get the layout as it supposed to be now.

Comment: Turns out this was a case of Android designer not showing the same as what you actually get. Looks like the grid view was way of the screen. Ive switched back to the LinearLayout version and got it back on the screen now by modifying some of the height attributes to not fill_parent. Not sure why the binding errors only occurred when grid was out of view but hey, least we have an answer.